# NHibernate Delete from Where COLUMN in (collection)

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate

I am trying to delete rows from a table using `where column in (collection)` using the following method:

```
public void DeleteRows(int parentId, List<int> years)
{
    var yearsAsCommaSeperatedString = ListToCommaSeperatedString(years);
    const string query = "DELETE FROM TABLE t WHERE t.PARENT_ID=:Parent AND t.YEAR in(:yearList)";
    Session
            .CreateSQLQuery(query)
            .SetParameter("Parent", parentId)
            .SetParameter("yearList", yearsAsCommaSeperatedString)
            .ExecuteUpdate();
}

private static string ListToCommaSeperatedString(IEnumerable<int> ints)
{
    var aggregate = ints.Aggregate("", (current, i) => current + (i + ", "));
    return aggregate.Substring(0, aggregate.LastIndexOf(",", StringComparison.Ordinal));
}
```

The problem is that `yearsAsCommaSeperatedString` is a string, therefor the db can not interpret it the numbers. I've also tried adding the list of integers as the parameter, but NHibernate does not know what to do with it.

How can i use `where in(collection)` with CreateSQLQuery?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use something like this

```
    ISession session = GetSession();
    string hql = @"from Product p
                   where p.Category in (:categories)";

    var categoriesToSearch = new[] {new Category {Id = 1}, new Category {Id = 2}};

    var query = session.CreateQuery(hql);
    query.SetParameterList("categories", categoriesToSearch);

    var products = query.List<Product>();
```

Or you can try this

```
public void DeleteRows(int parentId, List<int> years)
{        
    const string query = "DELETE FROM TABLE t WHERE t.PARENT_ID=:Parent AND t.YEAR in (:yearList)";
    Session
            .CreateSQLQuery(query)
            .SetParameter("Parent", parentId)
            .SetParameterList("yearList", years)
            .ExecuteUpdate();
}
```

Comment: that did not help me much. I dont have any mapped entities, i just want to delete som rows from a table. I tried to use a array instad of list, but that did not help me out.

Comment: +1 Your edited answer is the way to do it with NH - either with SQL or HQL queries.

Comment: @randoms if you don't have any mapped entities, what are you using NHibernate for??

Answer (score 1):

If your Method works, you can use the SetParamter again, but must change the SQL-Query to the follow:

```
var yearsAsCommaSeperatedString = ListToCommaSeperatedString(years);
const string query = "DELETE FROM TABLE t WHERE t.PARENT_ID=:Parent AND t.YEAR in(\":yearList\")";
Session .CreateSQLQuery(query)
        .SetParameter("Parent", parentId)
        .SetParameter("yearList", yearsAsCommaSeperatedString)
        .ExecuteUpdate();
```

Should be better than string concatenation (sql-injection) :)

Greetings